# In R, match a string and pull everything after it, until the next match

Tags: r

I have these three columns, c1,c2,c3 (plus others to be copied). And in each of these there are 6 letter IDs before a string. I want to copy the ID and everything after that, and move those into a new row that also copies all the other rows. However, I need it to stop at the next 6 letter tag in the same row and repeat. Note: some columns only have 1 tag per cell.

I have;

```
R1 <- c("PDFHRE; QZ4SDG", "PDFHRE [1103-1122]; QZ4SDG [1101-1120]", "PDFHRE 2xPhospho [S1106(100); T/S]; QZ4SDG 2xPhospho [S1104(100); T/S]", "blah1")
```

Want;

```
R1 <- c("PDFHRE", "PDFHRE [1103-1122]", "PDFHRE 2xPhospho [S1106(100); T/S]," "blah1")
R2 <- c("QZ4SDG", "QZ4SDG [1101-1120]", "QZ4SDG 2xPhospho [S1104(100); T/S]," "blah1")
```

Sometimes there are scenarios where I need to break this into three rows due to extra set of unmarked brackets;

```
R11 <- ("Qxsdf8; QSFDGJ", "Qxsdf8 [946-956]; [957-967]; QSFDGJ [912-922]" "Qxsdf8 1xPhospho [S948(100)]; 1xPhospho [S959(100)]; QSFDGJ 1xPhospho [S914(100)]", "blah2")
```

Desired output here is three rows;

```
R11 <- ("Qxsdf8", "Qxsdf8 [946-956]", "Qxsdf81xPhospho [S948(100)]", "blah2")
R12 <- ("Qxsdf8", "Qxsdf8 [957-967]", "Qxsdf81xPhospho [S959(100)]", "blah2")
R13 <- ("QSFDGJ", "QSFDGJ [912-922]", "QSFDGJ 1xPhospho [S914(100)]", "blah2")
```

Comment: This is not a clear question. I cant figure out what are you asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- These look like protein modifications - my code/documentation reflects this
- Every modification ends with "];" unless one of the following is true:

  - it is the last modification in the string
  - it is meta data similar to your "blah1" string in the example
- The modifications are listed in the same order in each string. e.g. if there are two protein IDs in the first string of modifications, there are always two protein IDs and they are always in the same order.

```
#' parse_mods
#' Parse peptide modifications from a string
#' 
#' @param R1 A vector of strings containing peptide modifications
#' @return A list of vectors containing the parsed modifications
parse_mods <- function(R1)
{
  # identify peptides
  peptide_ids <- str_split(R1[1], ";") |>
    unlist() |>
    str_trim()
  
  # split out modifications
  mods <- str_split(R1, fixed("];")) |>
    lapply(function(x) ifelse(grepl("\\[", x) & !grepl("\\]", x), paste0(x, "]"), x)) |> # add back missing brackets
    lapply(function(x) str_trim(x))
  
  retval <- list()
  for(i in 2:length(R1)) # skip the first element containing only peptide names
  {
    # if metadata, add the string to everything in retval
    if(length(mods[[i]]) == 1)
    {
      for(k in 1:length(retval))
      {
        retval[[k]] <- c(retval[[k]], R1[i])
      }
      next # skip ahead to the next modification
    }
    
    for(j in 1:length(mods[[i]]))
    {
      # check which peptide id we start with
      pepj <- which(sapply(peptide_ids, function(x) grepl(x, mods[[i]][[j]])))
      
      # if no peptide is found, then use the peptide id from the previous modification
      # and add it onto the current modification
      if(length(pepj) == 0)
      {
        pepj <- which(sapply(peptide_ids, function(x) grepl(x, mods[[i]][[j-1]])))
        mods[[i]][[j]] <- paste(names(pepj), mods[[i]][[j]])
      }
      
      # add result to retval
      if(length(retval) < j)
      {
        retval[[j]] <- names(pepj) # start each vector with the peptide id
      }
      
      retval[[j]] <- c(retval[[j]], mods[[i]][[j]])
    }
  }
  
  retval
}
```

For the "easy" case:

```
> R1 <- c("PDFHRE; QZ4SDG", "PDFHRE [1103-1122]; QZ4SDG [1101-1120]", "PDFHRE 2xPhospho [S1106(100); T/S]; QZ4SDG 2xPhospho [S1104(100); T/S]", "blah1")
> parse_mods(R1)
[[1]]
[1] "PDFHRE"                             "PDFHRE [1103-1122]"                
[3] "PDFHRE 2xPhospho [S1106(100); T/S]" "blah1"                             

[[2]]
[1] "QZ4SDG"                             "QZ4SDG [1101-1120]"                
[3] "QZ4SDG 2xPhospho [S1104(100); T/S]" "blah1"
```

For the more complicated case:

```
> R11 <- c("Qxsdf8; QSFDGJ", "Qxsdf8 [946-956]; [957-967]; QSFDGJ [912-922]", "Qxsdf8 1xPhospho [S948(100)]; 1xPhospho [S959(100)]; QSFDGJ 1xPhospho [S914(100)]", "blah2")
> parse_mods(R11)
[[1]]
[1] "Qxsdf8"                       "Qxsdf8 [946-956]"            
[3] "Qxsdf8 1xPhospho [S948(100)]" "blah2"                       

[[2]]
[1] "Qxsdf8"                       "Qxsdf8 [957-967]"            
[3] "Qxsdf8 1xPhospho [S959(100)]" "blah2"                       

[[3]]
[1] "QSFDGJ"                       "QSFDGJ [912-922]"            
[3] "QSFDGJ 1xPhospho [S914(100)]" "blah2"
```

For future questions, it would be helpful to include a little more information/detail and to double check that the code you post doesn't have errors in it.